# How to create blank table for written worksheet

Tags: tables, columns

I want to create a worksheet with a table for students to complete.  What's the simplest way to create space in the table so students have plenty room to write their answers?  Table code so far:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\times$ & $1$ & $r$ & $r^2$ & $s$ & $t$ & $u$ \\ 
\hline
$1$ &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
$r$ &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
$r^2$ &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
$s$ &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
$t$ &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
$u$ &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash $}X<{$}}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{7ex}}|*{7}{C|}}
\hline
\times & 1 & r & r^2 & s & t & u \\
\hline
1 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline
r &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline
r^2 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline
s &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline
t &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline
u &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Actually, I want to use this table for plain text not the math ones. But `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash $}X<{$}}` is making all the table entries into italicized math text. What should be changed in the code?

Comment: also can you please explain `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash $}X<{$}}`

Comment: If your table cells  haven't math contents, than remove `$˛` from `C` column definition: `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`. Fore more, consult `tabularx` package documentation or ask new question, where explain what is your problem. Planed content of your table is unknown, so it is difficult to advise you.